# reload jsp custom tag with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one `jsp` with some `custom tag`. Because of the security concerns, I have changed the tag file as the following. The field will be rendered as `<label>` when ever it contains readonly data and it will rendered as `text field` when it doesn't contain readonly data.

Below is the code I use.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${prot==true}">
         <label id="${jsvarname}">${status.value}</label>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <input type="text" name="${valueLocation}" id="${jsvarname}"/>
    </c:otherwise>
 </choose>
```

where `prot` is the value which specifies the field is readonly or not.

And now my problem is, by any `javascript` event, it can be changed to either of the fields. So I want to go for `ajax` to refresh the field. I know how to populate the data through `ajax` request. But I couldn't find any clue to reload the `jsp custom tag` with `ajax` request.

I am using spring mvc.

Any help with some code snippet will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand, I would suggest you implement a controller method that returns a view (JSP) that only contains your custom tag.

fragment.jsp:

```
<mytag prot="${protValue}" jsvarname="${jsvarnameValue}" valueLocation="${valueLocationVal}"/>
```

FragmentController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fragment-view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFragment(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("protValue", ...);
    model.put("jsvarnameValue", ...);
    model.put("valueLocationVal", ...);
    return "fragment";
}
```

You only have to invoke that method with AJAX and replace the old fragment with the html returned by the server.

Comment: It worked for me but with little effort of javascript. Thanks @WornOutSoles